# How to use np.where() to divide elements of an array into categories?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use np.where() to classify elements of an array into three categories. My array is `mean_house_value = [200.000, 120.000, 111.765, 326.234, 700.090, 99.345, 150.232, 250.000, 940.000, 177.000, 45.000, 42.000, 620.654]`. The dataset is called `housing`. `house_value_cat` is the new column in the dataset where I want to save my new classification. The classification is the following:

1. mean_house_value < 200.000
2. 200.000 < mean_house_value < 400.000
3. 400.000 < mean_house_value

My code so far is the following:

```
housing["house_value_cat"] = np.ceil(housing["mean_house_value"]/3)
housing["house_value_cat"].where((housing["house_value_cat"]<200.000) &(housing["house_value_cat"]>400.000))
print(housing["house_value_cat"])
```

How can I implement the second condition (`200.000 < mean_house_value < 400.000`) in my code?

[my desired output should look like this:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MFpE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy has a function digitize() that does what you want :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mean_house_value = [200.000, 120.000, 111.765, 326.234, 700.090, 99.345, 150.232, 250.000, 940.000, 177.000, 45.000, 42.000, 620.654]
>>> np.digitize(mean_house_value,[0.,200.,400.])
array([2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3])
```

You can create a new column in a dataframe with this result. Assuming you already defined a dataframe called housing :

```
housing["house_value_cat"] = np.digitize(mean_house_value,[0.,200.,400.])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I need the code to perform the comparison and eventually save the original elements in a new array instead of changing them 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Please update your question to show what is your desired output.

Comment: In your example mean_house_value is not an array but a list. Your desired output looks like a dataframe column, not an array either. np.digitize gives you an array, what you where asking for. You can easily create a new column in a dataframe with the result of np.digitize. I will edit my answer.